# Number of iterations to real time

Tags: animation

I have an animation of traffic. I have 20 cars in road network, each car have a starting node and end node. Each car know how much distance does it need to travel in order to reach the end node. I move cars each 20 ms for 10 px. To move all cars from their start node to end node I need 60 iterations. That is 60*20ms = 1200ms.

Now I want to convert this time, or use data that I have, to a real time where car move 50km/h. How can I do that? Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Distance between nodes` / `Speed` = `Travel time`

1km / 50kmh = 0.02hours

That means that if you have 1km between your nodes the time it should take a car to drive it is 1.2minutes.

Each update then should move a car by `Update step` * `Speed`. In you case that is 1/60/60/50hours * 50 = 0,00027777 kilometers. (Note that measurement units should match) More conveniently put - each 20ms car travels 0.27meters.

Comment: @Ivansek: What Krom shows here very well is that you get to define the scale. You get to choose how many pixels are equal to 1 meter and from that you can work out the 'real world' speed equivalents.